# Weird behaviour happens when using UIView animate and CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, cgaffinetransform, animatewithduration

I created some animations in my project. Basically, I use UIView animate and CGAffineTransform, but a very strange thing happened and I have no idea. Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

This is the strange thing:
After the user clicks on a button, the button slides off screen and another two buttons slide on the screen (I just changed the center point of these buttons to achieve this animation). And, some time later, a view on the screen start shaking (I use CGAffineTransform to achieve this).

At this moment, the strange thing happens - the button that previous slid off screen show up at its original position again and the other two buttons disappear (No animation, just shows up and disappear).

The following is the related code,

1) Button slide off and slide in animation related code

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    // 1. Slide in cancel and pause button
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        [startButton setCenter:CGPointMake(startButton.center.x + 300.0f, startButton.center.y)];
        [cancelButton setCenter:CGPointMake(cancelButton.center.x + 300.0f, cancelButton.center.y)];
        [pauseButton setCenter:CGPointMake(pauseButton.center.x + 300.0f, pauseButton.center.y)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            NSLog(@"Move finished");
        }
    }];
}
```

2) The view shaking animation related code

```
- (void)shakeView:(UIView *)viewToShake
{
    CGFloat t = 2.0;
    CGAffineTransform translateRight  = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, t, 0.0);
    CGAffineTransform translateLeft = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -t, 0.0);

    viewToShake.transform = translateLeft;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.07 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2.0];
        viewToShake.transform = translateRight;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                viewToShake.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            } completion:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: The code looks OK. Maybe you seek your problem somewhere else?

Comment: I checked, and I believe it is these two blocks of code that caused the problem. For example, if I change the animation in the shakeView method to a normal slide animation, the problem I mentioned above will not happen. So in this sense, I believe it is the conflict between these two chunks of code.

Comment: What's the relationship between the `viewToShake` and that three buttons? Is `viewToShake` their superview?

Comment: The viewToShake method is called at some particular time, and it has no link to those three buttons and it only controls the animation of that view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't weird, it's a common problem with
 auto layout. If you move UI elements by changing frames, then as soon as something else takes place that requires laying out views, the moved views will revert to the position defined by their constraints. To fix it, you either need to turn off auto layout, or do your animations by changing constraints not frames.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code in my test project. The problem is probably because you are using `Autolayout` in your xib.
Please checking your xib file and uncheck the `Autolayout` property.

Comment: Thanks, you are excellent. After I disabled auto layout, this problem never shows up again. Do you know why this problem happens when autolayout is enabled? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I think @rdelmar has explained it.