# Animating UIView changes frame position after TextField focus change

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, custom-controls, uiviewanimation

A strange problem after refactoring my code worth posting and get feedback, drives me crazy for the whole day.

I have a reusable custom control with it's XIB containing a UIView with subviews 3 UITextField (UserName, Password, Email), imagine it's a signup input box. I conform to the UITextFieldDelegate to act on keyboard Next, Return keyboard button press.

In all my views I heavily and carefully use AutoLayout constraints.

I initialize my nib in the file's owner UIView descendant custom class (SignUpInputView.m).

```
- (void) setupView
    {
    self.view = [self loadViewFromNib];
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.bounds = self.view.bounds;
    _intrinsicContentSize = self.bounds.size;
    [self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    self.view.layer.borderColor = [self greyColor];
    [self setupOutlets]; // I set the UITextFields delegate
    [self addSubview:self.view];
    }

// Override the intrinsicContectSize method

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
    {
    return _intrinsicContentSize;
    }
```

In the LoginViewController which derives from BaseViewController I use my custom control with a property setting the getter method.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, getter=getSignUpInputView) SignUpInputView* signUpInputView;

- (SignUpInputView*) getSignUpInputView
    {
    if (!_signUpInputView)
        {
        _signUpInputView = [SSESignUpInputView new];
        _signUpInputView.hidden = YES;
        _signUpInputView.alpha = 0.0f;
        [self.view addSubview:_signUpInputView];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_signUpInputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_signUpInputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_signUpInputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
        [_signUpInputView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_signUpInputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_signUpInputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
        }
    return _signUpInputView;
    }
```

I handle in the SignUpViewController the hidden and alpha properties according to actions that the user takes (push signup button, cancel button).

In the SignUpViewController I have a method when the user presses the SignUp button.

```
- (IBAction)signupButtonTouchUpInside:(UIButton*)sender
    {
    // Call a method that sets some animations

    // Set some other animations here.
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.uploadPhotoButton duration:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:
        ^{
        self.aView.alpha = 1.0f;
        self.anotherView.alpha = 0.0f;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }
    completion:nil];

    SignUpInputView* signUpView = self.signUpInputView;
    signUpView.hidden = NO;
    [signUpView fullNameBecomeFirstResponder];
    // This is a method from the BaseViewController
    [super animateViewFromLeftOffsetOnTopOfKeyboard:signUpView];
    }
```

The BaseViewController animateViewFromLeftOffsetOnTopOfKeyboard: implementation.

```
- (void) animateViewFromLeftOffsetOnTopOfKeyboard:(UIView*)view
    {
    // Execute with some delay to make sure I have the keyboard's height from the UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification
    [self executeBlock:
        ^{
        CGFloat yInputView = self.view.bounds.size.height - [self keyboardHeight] - view.bounds.size.height/2;
        view.center = CGPointMake(-view.bounds.size.width, yInputView);
        view.alpha = 1.0f;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.0f usingSpringWithDamping:0.8f initialSpringVelocity:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:
            ^{
            view.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width/2, yInputView);
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            }
        completion:nil];
        }
    withDelay:0.7];
    }
```

Everything works sweet, but now I have this error like it doesn't persist the `view.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width/2, yInputView);` in the `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` code block of the `animateViewFromLeftOffsetOnTopOfKeyboard:` method.

The problem, you tap to a textfield other than initial UITextField (full name, see code above at `signupButtonTouchUpInside:` method) and the SignUpInputView immediately moves to the top of the screen.

I miss something, but thing is it was working before refactoring the NSLayoutConstraints from the BaseController to the getter properties method because of crash of adding the constraints twice, and other general hidden,alpha properties manipulation.

Comment: See my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245878/weird-behaviour-happens-when-using-uiview-animate-and-cgaffinetransform/18246174#18246174

Comment: OK, turning off Auto Layout is out of question. Makes sense changing the center will change the frame. So setting the frame before adding it to the subview, then animate the constraint (maybe a center horizontal one) will fix my problem. Though I don't really know the exact position of the UIView introduces a challenge to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't set any frames at all. Add the subview, and give it constraints to set its initial position; make properties to any of those constraints that you want to modify. Change the constant value of those constraints to what you want then call layoutIFNeeded in the animation block.

Comment: OK, it makes sense, I'll have to start calculating constraints and not center or XY nowhere. Thanks for comment, will refactor and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Of course it works as expected now! It's a rule never to mess with XY positioning when you build for adaptive layout. Please answer below so that I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting any frames at all in this scenario. Add the subview, and give it constraints to set its initial position; make properties to any of those constraints that you want to modify. To animate the view, change the constant value of those constraints to what you want then call layoutIFNeeded in the animation block.